# Calling javaScript function named as innerHTML

Tags: javascript, function, innerhtml

I have an array of functions that I need to call depending on the innerHTML of a dom element.

The `.js` would be something like this:

```
var myFunctions = {
    'example1':function(){console.log("EXAMPLE 1")},
    'example2':function(){console.log("EXAMPLE 2")}
}
```

The HTML element where the function name is:

```
<div id="trigger">example1</div>
```

And the trigger I'm trying to implement would be something like this:

```
$('#trigger').click(triggerFunction);
```

Where triggerFunction tries to trigger the appropriate function when the user clicks on the element:

```
var triggerFunction = function(event){
    console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
    myFunctions.event.target.innerHTML();
}
```

Of course this way is NOT working, but I can't figure out how to solve this. :)

Hope I've been clear about what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: myFunctions[event.target.innerHTML]()

Comment: @dandavis Post it as an answer

Comment: Is there any reason why I've been down-voted? I'd like to know, so I don't make the same mistake next time I post a question =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply try this

```
var triggerFunction = function(event){
    console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
    myFunctions[event.target.innerHTML]() ;
}
```

a more robust way:

```
function triggerFunction(event){
    console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
    myFunctions[$.trim($(this).text())]() ;
}
```

Comment: because the listener is on `#trigger`, the element for which the innerHTML is desired, you can use `this` instead of `event.target`, too.

Comment: @PaulS.: good point. i like trim() too just in case, so i rolled both improvements into the answer.

Comment: Thanks a LOT, that was just what I needed, you save the day :D